# Can Visual Studio's Debug point you to the code you are debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

So, weird question. 
 I'm using Debug.WriteLine() to write out my output, but for any of my errors I'd love to see a reference or link to the code and line value for it. Can VS do that?

I got the idea on how Firebug/WebDev consoles do it.

Thanks,

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the StackTrace class to obtain this info.  Like this:

```
    public class Utils {
        public static string MyCaller {
            get {
#if DEBUG
                var trace = new StackTrace(true);
                var frame = trace.GetFrame(1);
                return frame.GetFileName() + "#" + frame.GetFileLineNumber().ToString();
#else
            return "N/A";
#endif
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Debug.Print("Hello world from {0}", Utils.MyCaller);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Hello world from C:\Users\hpassant\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs#10

Comment: I might go with this for now, but does the output window have the ability to have clickable values?

Comment: Erm, what?  Click the Ask Question button to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 can do this with Caller Information.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx

(Though not as a link but at least you get the information.)

Comment: That's exactly what I want, does anyone know of a backwards compatible or standalone for this feature? I'm using 2010 at work, and 2012 at home...